# JQuery - Multiple Select Options

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to grab all selected items in the following select multiple and separate them by a comma. The code is below:

```
<select id="ps-type" name="ps-type" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option>Residential - Wall Insulation</option>
    <option>Residential - Attic /Crawl Space Insulation</option>
    <option>Residential - Foundation Insulation</option>
    <option>Residential - Exterior Roof System</option>
    <option>Commercial - Wall Insulation</option>
    <option>Commercial - Air Barrier System (Walltite)</option>
    <option>Commercial - Roof System</option>
</select>
```

The result I am looking for is the following:

Residential - Wall Insulation, Commercial - Wall Insulation, ...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use the `:selected` selector, and the inline `$.map()` function as part of your chain.

```
$("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(", ");
```

Answer (score 24):

Add the values to an array and use `join` to create the string:

```
var items = [];
$('#ps-type option:selected').each(function(){ items.push($(this).val()); });
var result = items.join(', ');
```

Comment: You need the text() and not the val()

Comment: `val()` will actually still get the text from an option if there is no value attribute.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: Unless there is a value specified, the value is the text. If there is a value specified, you would most likely want the value instead.

Answer (score 12):

On a multiple select element, the `val` command of the `select` element will return an array of the selected options values. If no values are present, the text of the element is used:

```
var output = $("#ps-type").val().join(', ');
```

**update:** However, when there are no selected options `val()` returns `null` not an empty array. One way to get around this:

```
var output = ($("#ps-type").val() || []).join(', ');
```

You can play around with it in [this demo I put together](http://jsbin.com/umevi/2).

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option.

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .val() does in fact return an empty array when no options are selected.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var result = "";
$('#ps-type option:selected').each(function(i, item){ 
   result += $(this).val() + ", ";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = "";
$('#ps-type option:selected').each(function(){
  list += this.value + ", ";
});
return list.substr(0, list.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var result = new Array();

$("#ps-type option:selected").each(function() {
    result.push($(this).val());
});

var output = result.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
        $('#colorselector').change(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector" multiple="multiple" size="2">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some comments why you wrote/edited that code so others could understand.

Answer (score 1):

### The most simple solution

You could simply use just **`.val()`** like :

```js
console.log( $('#ps-type').val() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="ps-type" name="ps-type" multiple="multiple" size="5">
  <option selected>Residential - Wall Insulation</option>
  <option>Residential - Attic /Crawl Space Insulation</option>
  <option>Residential - Foundation Insulation</option>
  <option>Residential - Exterior Roof System</option>
  <option selected>Commercial - Wall Insulation</option>
  <option>Commercial - Air Barrier System (Walltite)</option>
  <option selected>Commercial - Roof System</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var List = new Array();
    $('#ps-type option:selected').each(function () {
       if ($(this).length) {
              var sel= {
                  name: $this.text()
              }
       }
       List.push(sel);
    });
    var result = List.join(', ');
```

Comment: _Try this_ answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Please improve your answer.