# Selecting Multiple <options> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

This question asks how to get all the selected `<options>` of a `<select>` element and return their values in a comma separated list. 
[JQuery - Multiple Select Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290181/jquery-multiple-select-options)

I would like to do the opposite of this question; I have a comma separated list of values for a `<select>` tag and would like to select each `<option>` whose value is in the comma separated list **using jQuery.**

**Example Data:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = "0a,0d,0f,0g";
</script>
<select id="ps-type" name="ps-type" multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <option value="0a">Residential - Wall Insulation</option>
    <option value="0b">Residential - Attic /Crawl Space Insulation</option>
    <option value="0c">Residential - Foundation Insulation</option>
    <option value="0d">Residential - Exterior Roof System</option>
    <option value="0e">Commercial - Wall Insulation</option>
    <option value="0f">Commercial - Air Barrier System (Walltite)</option>
    <option value="0g">Commercial - Roof System</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't give us points for doing your work for you. Try something yourself, first.

Comment: I did try with looping and it was the opposite of elegant. I'm not _that_ skilled at jQuery but I knew that there must a simpler way then using a loop. Also Google did provide any useful references so I came to the best knowledge base on the net to ask my question!

Comment: It's a good idea to include something you've tried in the question so we can either help you improve it or suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) also accepts an array of values as an argument. Thus, to select multiple values, just convert your comma-separated list of values to an array, using `split(",")`, and pass it to `.val()`:

```
var data = "0a,0d,0f,0g";
$("#ps-type").val(data.split(","));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxfBZ/)**.

Comment: I did not know .val() accepts an array! This does make it easier, I though for sure I was gonna have to loop...

Comment: `.val()` is a very versatile function eheh :-)

Comment: +1, very nifty. Thanks. I learned something new today. This one is going on my fiddle dashboard.

Comment: If you already have selected options, .val() will unselect them.
You would need to use something like 

`$("#ps-type").val($.merge($("#ps-type").val(),data.split(",")) );`

http://jsfiddle.net/7Szgd