# Using jquery, how can you reference the "option" array of a select control with multiple= true by using find()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Using jquery, I am trying to reference to selected Items from a select control that has multiple=true.  I need to reference it through name criteria and then loop through the list.  Here is my current code  (NOTE curre

```
 var currentRow = $(this); // this selected the current row in a table

 var selectedItems = currentRow.find($("[name='selectedItems']") + ' option');

 $(selectedItems).each(function (i, selected) {
      paramArray.push($(selected).val());
 });
```

The code seems to be failing in this line:

```
var selectedItems = currentRow.find($("[name='selectedItems']") + ' option');
```

so I am trying to figure out the correct way to reference the options when I need to find the select item dynamically (when i hard code like this:

```
var selectedItems = currentRow.find($('#mySelect option');
```

it works fine.

Comment: Perhaps `currentRow.find("[name='selectedItems'] option:selected");`

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290181/jquery-multiple-select-options) may help

Comment: can you please share the html

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.val()` directly instead like:

```
var selectedItems = currentRow.find("select[name='selectedItems']").val();
```

```js
console.log($('body').find("select[name='selectedItems']").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectedItems" multiple>
  <option value="Big Island">Big Island</option>
  <option value="Oahu" selected>Oahu</option>
  <option value="Kauai">Kauai</option>
  <option value="Maui" selected>Maui</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was unexpected

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var currentRow = $("#row1");

var paramArray = currentRow.find("[name='selectedItems'] option:selected")
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get(); 
console.log(paramArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>
      <select name="selectedItems" multiple>
        <option value="Big Island">Big Island</option>
        <option value="Oahu" selected>Oahu</option>
        <option value="Kauai">Kauai</option>
        <option value="Maui" selected>Maui</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However I learned something today from Zakaria:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

> When the first element in the collection is a select-multiple (i.e., a
>   select element with the multiple attribute set), .val() returns an
>   array containing the value of each selected option. As of jQuery 3.0,
>   if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to jQuery
>   3.0, it returns null.

so `currentRow.find("[name='selectedItems']").val()` will also work