# Chrome forgets to send form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-chrome

I have a form with two select inputs that are used to pick values from a list using some simple jquery script. Think of it as a lightweight picklist.

For the sake of testing I have reduced everything to the bare minimum. The form now only contains one text input for sanity, and the two selects for showing and picking data.
Basically it comes down to this:

```
<form>
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <select></select>                     <!-- contains search results -->
    <select name="members[]"></select>    <!-- contains the current selection -->
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

The javascript attaches an event listener to the `select` elements in order to allow the user to select and deselect values, which are moved from one to the other.

On submit, javascript selects all values in `members[]` so that they will be sent in the POST request.

With *Firefox* and *Safari*, everything works. Submitting the form sends the auto-selected values from `members[]` to the server. Any combination of selecting, deselecting, works fine.

With *Chrome* (102.0.5005.115) however, strange behavior is observed:

- nothing changes: all values from `members[]` are POSTed
- 1 value added: all values from `members[]` are POSTed
- 1 value removed: **no values from `members[]` are POSTed**
- 1 value removed and re-added: **only that value from `members[]` is POSTed**
- 1 value added and 1 removed: **no values from `members[]` are POSTed**

It seems that manipulating the contents of the `members[]` select box sometimes confuses Chrome and makes it forget to send the values across.

I have a JSFiddle where this can be tested. The form is not submitted in this test but the serialization is logged to console and shows the described erroneous behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/y54fq7L6/1/

**Has anyone seen this happen? Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: You're changing the selected *property* so use `.prop`:  `$('#member-selected option').prop('selected', 'selected');`   https://jsfiddle.net/t209zaqg/

Comment: _That simple_ huh? So, the other browsers just correct this automagically? But why does Chrome accept the _selected_ attr() when nothing has changed?

Comment: Also: use `:selected` to get the options that are selected:  `$('#member-selected option:selected').length)`    https://stackoverflow.com/a/2290280/2181514

Comment: All I can imagine is because you're using `clone()`/`append()`/`remove()` which updates the original HTML so stores in-memory so needs prop - without changes *I guess* it will not have in-memory version so attr also works.... maybe?  (BTW you only need `.append() which *moves* but does leave it selected)

Comment: Thank you, solved my headache. If you answer this I will mark as accepted. And yes the in-memory explanation does make sense.

Comment: BTW I like the `append()` only but that shows 'ugly' selected and unselected values together. More efficient code but less clean visibly.